# Make title horizontally in vertical tabpanel

Tags: extjs4.2, tabpanel

Is there a way to get horizontal titles in a vertical tabpanel in extjs 4.2? I can't find the correct property.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal title in side tabs (left, right) are not supported in Ext 4.x. If you can, upgrade to 5.x and configure `rotation` config option on tabs.

If you cannot upgrade, you need to develop custom css that will be applied to side tabs to achieve the look you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and also for you website!)

Comment: i can't upgrade there are many things stuck, could provide example do with custom or css?

Comment: I do not use horizontal titles in side tabs so I do not have any example of that.